# Controller actions dependent on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

simple question here
I'm trying to define a variable in my controller based on what environment my app is deployed in. Specifically, I want to search for products by any string or partial string in the name, using the SQL term LIKE in my dev. environment and iLIKE in the production environment.

This is what I have, but I'm running into an invalid statement error. I'm quite green with ruby and rails, so I think it may be a syntax error. Thoughts?

Thanks!

products_controller:

```
def index
  if Rails.env.development? == "development"
    name_env = "name LIKE ?"
    else
    name_env = "name ilike ?"
    end 

  if params[:q]
    search_term = params[:q]
    @products = Product.where(name_env, "%#{search_term}%")
  else
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

Comment: you don't need to ask `Rails.env.development? == "development"`, `Rails.env.development?` is enough. I don't see any errors here, but, trying that `ilike` on my env throws an error cos I don't have that extension installed... do you have it installed?

Comment: Aha, I think this would work to but I went with 'if Rails.env == "development" construction instead since it worked and I tried it first. Interesting, I didn't have to install the extension. I'm deploying on heroku, so maybe it's supported? I'll look into it more and post the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are asking Rails if it is in development mode and Rails responds you with true (which is different of "development")

irb> Rails.env.development?
 => true

What you could do is remove the development after Rails.env so it will be equal to the String "development"

irb> Rails.env
 => "development"

Or just remove the part where you compare to the String "development" since Rails.env.development? returns a Boolean

Comment: Thanks Rantelo, I thought about what you said and updated it to look like this:
`def index //
  if Rails.env == "development" //
    name_env = "name LIKE ?" //
    else //
    name_env = "name ilike ?" //
    end //

  if params[:q] //
    search_term = params[:q] //
    @products = Product.where(name_env, "%#{search_term}%") //
  else //
    @products = Product.all //
  end //
end`
It works perfectly. Thanks again (sry not sure how to add line breaks in comments)

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- `Rails.env.development? == "development"` is not correct, I think it should be `Rails.env.development?`, because `Rails.env.development?` returns true/false already
- The query string will be "name LIKE '%?%'", because if just use `name LIKE ?", it is not enough!

In summary, your code would be:

```
def index
  name_env = if Rails.env.development?
    "name LIKE '%?%'"
  else
    "name ilike '%?%'"
  end 

  search_term = params[:q]
  @products = if search_term
    Product.where(name_env, search_term)
  else
    Product.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I like your `if/else` construction. :)

Comment: Ahh I see, Rails.env.development? is a boolean. I wasn't sure. It still isn't functioning unfortunately, but I will post the code when it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rails.env.development? == "development" would be false in development as Rails.env.development? would be true in development